# How do you preview/ run a Java program in Nitrous.IO?

Tags: java, nitrousio

I am just starting to use Nitrous.IO and I can't seem to find any information on the web on how to run Java programs you make in it. Any help on how to run a java app made in Nitrous would be a huge help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the version of Java by running `java -version`, which shows Java SE is installed. This does not include all of the components of JDK8, but you can still build Java apps on it. Take a look at the [JDK8 diagram](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/) for an overview of the components included.

To build a simple hello world app, create a new file titled `HellowWorldApp.java` with the following contents:

```
/**
 * The HelloWorldApp class implements an application that
 * simply prints "Hello World!" to standard output.
 */
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
```

Once saved, run the following command to build a class file:

```
javac HelloWorldApp.java
```

You should now have a file named `HelloWorldApp.class`. Run this application with the following command:

```
java HelloWorldApp
```

Currently you can utilize this on any box template on Nitrous, but there will be full Java support in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a new project using Maven and everything seems to work fine.
More details on: Maven Getting Started Guide http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/

But when I installed the Play framework (https://www.playframework.com/) and run a project i.e:

```
activator "~run 8080"
```

and previewed at http://my_box_name.nitrousbox.com::8080/ The web app suddenly died, with a log message: "killed"

After a short research it seems that I do not have enough resources on my box for this type of development (have to buy more N2O :) ).

In conclusion it is okay to use Nitrous for Java Development, especially for prototyping things (Plus they are currently working to make it better). Good luck !